# SMTP server that saves all mail to a folder?

Tags: testing, smtp

Are there any free SMTP servers that just accept the mail sent through them, and save it to your hard disk, without sending it to the recipient.  I would like to use this for  testing my applications.  Instead of just waiting around for the mail to go through, it would be nice if all emails could just be dropped in a folder, so that I can look at them.  I could put some hooks into my program to just save instead of sending the message, but I don't think it's a full test, if the code follows a different path.  Are there any existing applications like this?

I figure this would be really helpful, because you could test the mail abilities without needing to wait for the mail server to deliver it, and so that you can code while you're offline, and don't have access to an actual mail server.

[EDIT]

I'm specifically using .Net, but I'm not using the default SMTP mail handling classes in .Net, because of how limited they were in .Net 1.1.  We are using a third party library (chilkat).  I know that things have changed since then, but the code is stable and works, so no point in rewriting against the .Net API now.

I would like something that works as an SMTP server specifically because I could use it in the future for whatever projects I worked on, no matter the language.

Comment: Stating your prefered platform would help.

Comment: Erm... It's clearly programming related.

Comment: (But the platform should be specified)

Comment: Windows is the preferred platform at this point, although multiplatform would be nice too.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- [Papercut](https://github.com/changemakerstudios/papercut)
- [Neptune](http://www.donovanbrown.com/post/2008/10/20/Neptune.aspx)
- [SMTP4Dev](https://github.com/rnwood/smtp4dev)
- [Dumbster](http://quintanasoft.com/dumbster/)
- [DevNull SMTP](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DevNullSmtp.jsp)

Taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006650/dummy-smtp-server-for-testing-apps-that-send-email/).

Answer (score 15):

You can use the standard smtp settings in your app or web.config and just specify what folder you want the emails to go.

```
<smtp
  deliveryMethod="specifiedPickupDirectory" 
  from="from address">
  <specifiedPickupDirectory>Your folder here</specifiedPickupDirectory>
</smtp>
```

This allows you to simply store the emails without an smtp server

Comment: The idea is to get a test of the app as close to its nominal usage as possible.  So unless that is the configuration to use in production it would be better to use a catch all smtp server

Comment: Good idea.  However, I'm not using the .Net mail handling classes (although I'm working in .Net), so I don't think this will work for me.

Comment: Hi Anthony. because its nice and declarative and you're not testing SMTPClient who cares on the implementation?  As long as you trust the .NET framework to work, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: This seems out of date - I think the correct syntax is: `<specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="Your folder here"/>` (tested on .NET Framework 4.5.2)

Answer (score 4):

On windows you could use IIS server's default SMTP server.  Add an alias to its domain for * (wildcard) should cause it to drop all mail forwarded to it into its drop folder.

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly easy to do in sendmail or postfix - just configure the local delivery agent to be 'cat >> file'.

Comment: +1 Postfix is also fairly easy to set up and IIRC comes with cygwin.

Answer (score 3):

bit late on this one, but have you tried [ssfd](http://ssfd.codeplex.com/)?

you can put it on your machine or on a network server, catches e-mails and pops them in a directory

Answer (score 2):

There is the python DebuggingServer as well part of the standard library :

http://docs.python.org/library/smtpd.html#debuggingserver-objects

it will print everything on stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about such "fake" SMTP servers, but in .NET you can force SmtpClient class to save outgoing mail to the specified directory.

Answer (score -1):

I am years late to the party but this works great for me.

http://emailrelay.sourceforge.net/

Having the .net email client just save the email and not send it
does not answer the question if your code works. To tell if it works
you must actually send it.

Comment: Why did this get a downvote it seems to do what was requested?

Comment: Maybe because sourceforge is putting adwares in your downloads: http://www.howtogeek.com/218764/warning-don%E2%80%99t-download-software-from-sourceforge-if-you-can-help-it/