# Catch-all SMTP server + GUI

Tags: java, smtp

I was reading [this post about a NetBeans plugin](http://blogs.i2m.dk/allan/2009/07/10/smtp-dummy-1-1-released-netbeans-plugin/) which intercepts all SMTP traffic and stores it for display.

[screenshot http://img216.imageshack.us/img216/4733/picture1ezb.png](http://img216.imageshack.us/img216/4733/picture1ezb.png)

I find it a great tool for developing locally when you have lots of email interaction and don't want to create {x} accounts.

Is there any such **cross-platform** tool available outside of NetBeans?

Comment: Yes. I asked the same question a few weeks ago an got some good suggestions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006650/dummy-smtp-server-for-testing-apps-that-send-email

Comment: Thanks, I managed to miss it. I just added 'cross-plaftorm' since all those apps seem to be windows-specific or without GUIs. Not really sure if my question should me merged into yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MailSnag](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/foos-bar/) is an Eclipse plugin that acts as a dummy SMTP server to capture and inspect emails sent out from an application during development. Each email can be viewed in a multi-tab editor displaying Text, HTML or raw format. A tab listing attachments is also displayed.

[image: MailSnag screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

For JUnit testing I like to use [Dumbster](http://quintanasoft.com/dumbster/).  It sets up a nice little server in your unit tests that holds the messages you send so you can then use JUnit assertions to validate your code is sending the right thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a nice app, but if only it had a GUI.