# Need Smtp Server for Windows that wont deliver email

Tags: email, smtp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dummy SMTP Server for testing apps that send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006650/dummy-smtp-server-for-testing-apps-that-send-email)

My dev machine is Win 7 pro x64.

I would like to install an SMTP server on it that wont deliver email, but will respond to clients as if it did. Any recommendations?

Comment: mailsnag.com does that plus some error simulation for reliability and fault tolerance testing. Highly recommend

Comment: I asked this question much earlier in my career. A couple of years ago, I read some smtp related RFC's and wrote an smtp delivery server from scratch that auto creates mailbox folders on disk and stores messages there.  Mainly for fun and learning, but I do tend to use this solution when I need it.

Answer (score 7):

[Papercut](http://invalidlogic.com/papercut/) will do this: http://invalidlogic.com/papercut/

From the Papercut website:

> "Ever need to test emails from an application, but don't necessarily want it sending them out? Don't want to hassle with pointing it to a physical SMTP server? All you want to is verify it can send email, and take a look at the message.
>
> Papercut is your answer. Papercut is a simplified SMTP server designed to only receive messages (not to send them on) with a GUI on top of it allowing you to see the messages it receives. It doesn't enforce any restrictions on addresses, it just takes the message and allows you see it. It is only active while it is running, and if you want it in the background, just minimize it to the system tray. When it receives a new message, a balloon message will show up to let you know."

Answer (score 1):

I tried out 3 programs, all of which worked great:

- [Devnull SMTP Server](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DevNullSmtp.jsp) (cross platform)
- [PaperCut](http://invalidlogic.com/papercut) (can view emails without an email client)
- [smtp4dev](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com) (most configurable)

Answer (score 0):

Use any SMTP server (I use [hMail](http://www.hmailserver.com/)) and configure it to forward all mails to an internal account.