# Configure PHP to send all mail to one account only

Tags: php, email

How can I configure PHP to send all outgoing mail to my own account so that I can test a business application without actually sending mails to unsuspecting businesses, such as "Congratulations, you have a new account. You will be billed for $xxx" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this site: http://dummysmtp.com/.

My server is running qmail, so I edited the contents of /var/qmail/control/smtproutes like so:

> :smtp.dummysmtp.com *username* *password*

It worked when I sent a simple mail with PHP mail(), but later I found that mail is still getting out to other people.  I had to crawl into the bowels of the code and found this:

```
/* Choose the mailer */
switch($this->Mailer) {
  case 'sendmail':
    $result = $this->SendmailSend($header, $body);
    break;
  case 'smtp':
    $result = $this->SmtpSend($header, $body);
    break;
  case 'mail':
    $result = $this->MailSend($header, $body);
    break;
  default:
    $result = $this->MailSend($header, $body);
    break;
    //$this->SetError($this->Mailer . $this->Lang('mailer_not_supported'));
    //$result = false;
    //break;
}
```

So I had to make sure that each option was configured to send its mail to dummysmtp.com.  Once I got that figured out, it all worked.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than configuring PHP, a generalized solution would be to stand up a dummy SMTP server.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006650).

Comment: Thanks.  I already looked at that thread.  All the solutions either required Windows, or were for Java servers.  I'm on linux and my MTA is qmail.  I did find a better solution and I'm testing it now.  If it works, I'll post a response to my own question.

Comment: @Fosco, can you justify why it's a terrible idea?
@Isiden, the SMTP servers suggested run on Java, not your app.

Comment: Well, instead of limiting the change to just the one application during testing, now the entire server is incapable of sending legitimate emails.  See Isiden's post below re: his solution...

Comment: Yes, the entire TEST *server* is isolated from the PRODUCTION environment.

Answer (score 0):

So you already wrote the application and it uses live email addresses, and now you want to test it?  Did you use a centralized function for mail or are there tons of mail() calls all over the code?  Sorry but you're going to have to change every mail() call.  Do yourself a favor and replace them all with your own function, and then handle test/live functionality in that one location.

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't write the application.  I have a copy of the database and I tried to change all the email addresses to my own, but the database is not normalized and there are still many tables with live e-mail addresses that I haven't found yet.

Comment: I was suggesting you change the function that sends the email, not the database.  The email address is used as a parameter in the mail() function and you could replace it with your own.

Comment: --; Suggesting that the OP hardcode configuration data? For shame.

Comment: How about enabling the configuration to go into 'testing' mode and having a 'testing email address' to route all emails to.  That's what I'm suggesting.. not hardcoding configuration data.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect all port 25 traffic on the server running PHP to a mailserver/port which delivers all mail to you.

This is the only 100% foolproof method of which I know.

Comment: Are you referring to iptables?  That's interesting, but I think I found a more elegant solution, at least for now.

Comment: @Isiden Yes, using iptables you can do this :-).  I'm glad you've got a solution, whatever it is.

Comment: Well, not quite.  I found that mail is still getting out to other people.  I tried 


sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 65.19.154.62

but got
iptables: Unknown error 4294967295

The IP address is to smtp.dummysmtp.com

Comment: @Isiden: why are you using the nat table?  Shouldn't you be using mangle?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Google Apps account (or use your dummy server), create a catch-all email account and have it sent to the domain. All you would have to do is look at the catch-all account.

Comment: Thank you.  That sounds similar to what I'm describing below when I found a solution.  

How do you create a dummy server?