# Test sending email without email server

Tags: django, email, mail-server

I have a Django application that sends an email.  The production server has an email server but my local box does not.  I would like to be able to test sending of email locally.  Is there any way that I can have django not send it through the email server and just print out to a file or console?

Comment: The operating system of your local box might be a useful thing to know here... You don't actually need an email server on the box anyway, all you need is a network connection to an email server via the SMTP port... and possible user/password.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dummy SMTP Server for testing apps that send email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006650/dummy-smtp-server-for-testing-apps-that-send-email)

Comment: mailsnag.com is built for that. It works with any framework and has some nice features for fault simulations

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can [configure your application to use the Console Backend](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#console-backend) for sending e-mail. It writes e-mails to standard out instead of sending them.

Change your settings.py to include this line:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Don't forget to remove it for production.

Comment: Better yet, put it in a development settings file and don't add it to production.

Comment: Or even better yet, [do it with environment variables](http://12factor.net/config).

Comment: If you're using [`mail_admins`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/email/#mail-admins), remember to set [`ADMINS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-ADMINS) to something, otherwise nothing will get print to stdout. Similarly for `mail_managers`.

Answer (score 85):

Python has a little SMTP server [built-in](http://docs.python.org/library/smtpd.html). You can start it in a second console with this command:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

This will simply print all the mails sent to `localhost:1025` in the console.

You have to configure Django to use this server in your `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
```

Comment: Note that your app may throw an exception if it tries to send an email  when the email server isn't started. `fail_silently=False` is the default for `send_mail`.

Comment: While Daniel Hepper's answer is undoubtedly the correct one with respect to the question posed, I like this answer better because it's a general solution that works regardless of environment. (Upvotes on both though, of course.)

Answer (score 42):

You can configure your application to write emails out to temporary files instead of sending them (similar to Daniel Hepper's answer).

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = 'tmp/email-messages/'
```

This saves each new message as a separate file. Useful if you are sending heaps of emails, and don't want to have to use the scrollback.

Answer (score 35):

If your tests extends from django.test.testcases.TestCase then nothing has to be done. Django will replace the EmailBackend to a "special" one. Then you can test what would had been sent like this :

```
def testMethodThatSendAEmail(self):
    ...
    from django.core import mail
    object.method_that_send_email(to='me@example.com')
    self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)
    self.assertEqual(mail.outbox[0].to, ['me@example.com'])
    ...#etc
```

The outbox object is a special object that get injected into mail when 
python manage.py test is run.

Comment: Man this is great.

Answer (score 13):

This elaborates on the answer from Benjamin. One way that I test emails if I don't have a local email server like postfix, sendmail or exim installed is to run the python email server. You can run it on port 25 with sudo, or just use a port > 1024 (reserved ports):

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
#sudo python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:25
```

For testing with your current django app code, you can change settings.py temporarily to include this at the botom:

```
EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT, EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'localhost', 1025, None, None
```

Now test out your emails, or you can do this in ./manage.py shell in another terminal window like so:

```
python manage.py shell
```

And paste in this code to send an email:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail​
send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'messanger@localhost.com',['any@email.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

No need to use any real emails since you will see everything in your terminal. You can dump it to the appropriate container like .html for further testing.

Answer (score 11):

There is a cool app for this by caktus https://github.com/caktus/django-email-bandit
Just add this to your settings.py file:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'bandit.backends.smtp.HijackSMTPBackend'
BANDIT_EMAIL = 'your_email@example.com'
```

On top of your email setttings..All emails will be diverted to 'your_email@example.com'

Happy coding...