# Email verification after signup code works but email is not sent

Tags: python, django

My code works and outputs the email to the console but I don't receive any email in my inbox.

My settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youremail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in settings.py to print the email on console.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Refer: [Test sending email without email server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642011/test-sending-email-without-email-server)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set EMAIL_BACKEND in setting like this.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Second, you need to define SMTP credentials details in settings.

For development on localhost, you can run local SMTP server by running following command on terminal.

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

For more info [Sending email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/)