# How do you unit test a mail sending function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have a function which creates a report and sends it to a user.
What I've done is create a mock for the email function, and verify if the 'send' function of the email class was called.

So now I know that the function is called, but how do you unit test the body of the Send() function? How can I prove that the subject and body are correct and an attachment is attached to the email?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mockemail/

Comment: Could you please provide some code? What does the Send-Method looks like?

Comment: You may also find you need to change virus checker settings on the test machine, as often a virus checker blocks emails going out to a test email server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unit test email sending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252980/how-to-unit-test-email-sending)

Comment: @ArturINTECH Thanks for the comment, but 12 years after posting this question I'm not actively looking for answers anymore.

Comment: @Michel Understand. This comment was apparently generated automatically after I linked another question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Can be done in following ways.

Step 1: Navigate to your `Web.Config` file and add the following tags to it.

```xml
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
            <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="E:\MailTest\"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Make sure the directory you have specified for pickup location must exist.

Step 2 : Now test your email sending functionality. I have used `button_click` to test this functionality with the following code.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
MailMessage message = new MailMessage("me@gmail.com", "me@yahoo.com","My Message Subject","This is a test message");
smtp.Send(message);
```

Output : It will create `.eml` files inside the folder with a randonly generated GUID name, which is the email that we can see after receiving it.
For me it created a file like `c127d1d5-255d-4a5a-873c-409e23002eef.eml` in `E:\MailTest\` folder

Hope this helps :)

Comment: this is actualy a very nice solution. I must say i didn't believe it would work, but it does...

Comment: This is a great solution when creating automated tests for a web application that has to send e-mails. No more rejected e-mails from the test.com or example.com e-mail servers! +1

Comment: May be a nice solution but **this is not a unit test**.

Answer (score 14):

In your unit test tell your mocking framework to expect a call to `Send()` with a specific body text.

Example for Rhino Mocks:

```
var mockMail = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Mail>();
mockMail.Expect( m => m.Send("ExpectedFrom", "ExpectedTo", "ExpectedSubject", "ExpectedBodytext") );

mockMail.Send(...whatever...);

mockProvider.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

Answer (score 9):

I recently ran into this issue myself. Try using http://netdumbster.codeplex.com/.
This library allows you to spin up a local SMTP server and check which mails it received. This is all handled in memory AFAIK so the perfomance impact on your test should be minimal.

In your test you create the server like this

```cs
SimpleSmtpServer server = SimpleSmtpServer.Start(25);
```

Then just change the config of your mail sender class to use the local smtp server (localhost:25).
After the mail is send you can access it like this

```cs
server.ReceivedEmail[0]
```

And use the Data or MessageParts property to check for subject, body and attachments.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried nDumbster, and it did work, but in my case a simple test <10ms exploded to 12 seconds.  Unsure if it was just my config or not.

Comment: to which email should i send the email so that my fake server receives it ?

Comment: @Mortalus If I remember correctly, netDumbster caught all mails that were send through it per default.

Comment: @DanielRosendorf thanks for the quick response :) lol.. 
really man what made you comment on this after 5 years

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple way to test the email contents in approvaltests (www.approvaltests.com)or nuget)

The code is simply:

```
 EmailApprovals.Verify(mail);
```

This will create the .eml file, and allow you to view the result in outlook. Future .more, once you approve the result (rename the file to .approved) the test will pass without opening Outlook.

I have created and uploaded a short video on the process to [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sf16dPq2n3w).

Answer (score 1):

At least in my case, all email sending is encapsulated in a 'MailService' class - and all send calls go through a send method in the class.  The send method is virtual - and all it does is new up an SmtpClient, send the mail, etc.  For my unit tests, I have a private class MailServiceMock, that overrides send and does nothing.  All of the other methods can be tested - but send is short-circuited.

oleschri has provided an easier way to do this using Rhino Mocks (I think any mocking framework would work fine) - however if you are hesitant to introduce another dependency, this can get your feet wet with mocking by hand.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have sent real e-mails but I used the decorator pattern on the default EMailGateway implementation.

So I had an EMailGatewayRedirect that would change the recipient to my own address and, in my case, added a line to the top stating that the e-mail is a test and what the original recipient address was.

Since I use a DI container I simply instantiated the redirection gateway as my IEMailGateway implementation in my integration tests.  In this way a real e-mail was sent.

Comment: Ok until you get the setup wrong and a 1001 test emails go to real people!  (As if I have never seen this problem....)

Comment: With great power comes great responsibility! *lol* --- just don't get the config wrong ;)