# Trying to send mail in a localhost XAMPP Windows environment using PHP's mail() function?

Tags: php, email, xampp

...But I'm not getting anywhere fast. I've actually been building this website under a Mac environment with MAMP and it works perfectly, but now I need to hand it in to my teacher who's using XAMPP on Windows (unsure which version), and everything works except for this one mail() function. My home PC, which has XAMPP 1.8.0 installed, will not send my `mail()` function which I call in a file called `register.php`. It returns `false` upon execution. A few years ago I remember getting mail() to work under a windows environment, but things have changed quite a bit and XAMPP is no longer as familiar as it once was.

I've tried looking in php.ini and the sendmail config file, and I can't get a single thing working.

Can anyone think of any settings I need to configure? I simply want to send email from a local test environment with no external SMTP servers at all. Thanks.

Comment: "no external SMTP servers " then you would need to install a local one

Comment: you said sendmail documents, you mean you have a local mail server installed?

Comment: @Dagon, then how did I manage to send mail through PHP & XAMPP a year or so ago?

Comment: you probably used an eternal mail server ISP\gmail ..

Comment: @Dagon. Nope. I'm certain of that.

Comment: well im certain php has no magic that can send mail with out a mail server

Comment: @Dagon he used Mac back then (based on his post), Anti mac has a mail server as part of the OS.

Comment: There isn't (in theory) any way that the `mail()` function will work without a mail server. We can't figure out how it worked earlier, because there is no logical reason it should, based on the data we have.

Comment: Ahh, the magic of macs :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need a local SMTP server for that in Windows, you can configure it using this one:

http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/

you can get further help from here
[How to develop and test an app that sends emails (without filling someone's mailbox with test data)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006650/how-to-develop-and-test-an-app-that-sends-emails-without-filling-someones-mail/1006679#1006679)